# Devtools integration

Tags: java, docker, microservices, devtools

I have added
CompileOnly("org.springframework.boot: spring-boot-devtools")
to build.gradle
Still need to do debug service to restart the service. I am working on microservices

I have followed all the steps properly. Help me with the steps to integrate devtools in spring boot service.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.